# How do I extend the y-axis range in an autocorrelation plot?

Tags: plot, graph, stata

I have fit a linear regression model to some data in Stata and now I want to generate the [Residual Autocorrelation Plot](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/autocopl.htm) with respect to the variable `id`.

Below you can find the variables generated from the regression:

```
clear
input id response pred_response stud_res
    101 72 57.55613  1.512287
    102 61 51.24638  1.010817
    103 49 56.94838 -0.8237054
    104 48 43.1188   0.5078933
    105 51 60.35182 -0.9997848
    106 49 43.1188   0.6123365
    107 50 43.60501  0.6678697
    108 58 67.50063 -1.00277
    109 50 45.17883  0.5053187
    110 51 45.66593  0.5525671
    111 59 62.28483 -0.3425483
    112 65 52.94175  1.259024
    113 57 59.49549 -0.2584414
    114 53 59.00929 -0.6238151
    115 74 68.10928  0.6212816
    116 50 54.2797  -0.4418168
    117 84 68.35238  1.671826
    118 46 50.27308 -0.4435438
    119 52 48.0915   0.4033695
    120 64 58.04234  0.6188389
    121 59 45.17972  1.444254
    122 55 54.51646  0.0500989
    124 46 44.33432  0.1745929
    125 52 51.48948  0.0526441
    126 63 64.71586 -0.1833892
    127 52 51.00238  0.1038181
    128 42 43.84811 -0.1929091
    129 57 63.62279 -0.6922547
    130 23 42.75415 -2.098808
    131 65 58.88685  0.6355278
    132 38 48.45526 -1.100601
    133 59 54.77137  0.4510341
    134 26 43.72021 -1.880954
    135 53 60.46791 -0.7770496
    136 50 40.68689  0.9796554
    137 56 51.9748   0.4227943
    138 49 65.43971 -1.751305
    139 76 68.83858  0.7565064
    140 68 66.53456  0.1536334
    141 60 49.66532  1.077015
    142 46 43.72021  0.2374953
    143 57 59.85926 -0.2981544
    144 45 48.45615 -0.3568231
    145 46 45.42282  0.0596576
    146 64 67.13597 -0.3291895
    147 40 41.9024  -0.1997022
    148 62 64.7104  -0.283202
    149 13 45.78748 -3.629334
    150 79 63.25813  1.66337
    151 61 59.86015  0.1180355
    152 46 42.02484  0.4124526
    153 50 45.66593  0.4487194
    154 48 51.61103 -0.3727813
    155 65 59.37306  0.5858857
    156 62 69.08168 -0.748562
    157 56 54.5228   0.1524598
    158 54 52.09724  0.196739
    159 72 60.46156  1.209799
    160 57 60.83167 -0.4032753
    161 50 41.6593   0.8780965
    162 65 55.97507  0.9392686
    163 56 66.28511 -1.086957
    201 54 49.5392   0.4779044
    202 57 50.02451  0.7322617
    203 48 49.18    -0.1222386
    204 41 41.66019 -0.0684602
    205 34 38.38376 -0.4576099
    206 54 54.511   -0.0545433
    207 38 40.68777 -0.2798446
    208 49 41.77539  0.7603746
    209 58 54.63255  0.3589811
    210 14 47.24063 -3.676064
    211 40 39.47226  0.0554914
    212 13 39.71537 -2.931103
    213 51 45.17426  0.611295
    214 44 54.39491 -1.084383
    216 42 48.08604 -0.6381954
    217 55 46.38978  0.8958285
    301 62 63.86043 -0.1954589
    302 37 43.23401 -0.6509517
    303 46 44.57196  0.147607
    304 59 59.8538  -0.0890346
    305 35 41.66019 -0.6924483
    306 70 66.77221  0.3416052
    307 56 58.15843 -0.2244185
    308 45 46.99207 -0.2117317
    309 50 47.47739  0.2635025
    310 52 46.87598  0.5302449
    311 52 59.84834 -0.8546749
    312 83 49.78776  3.674294
    313 57 54.03025  0.3084902
    314 38 44.57196 -0.680949
    315 40 48.81446 -0.9177504
    410 48 39.59927  0.8789283
    415 50 40.92999  0.9539063
    605 42 36.31649  0.6024827
end
```

When I generate this graph, the default range for the vertical axis is set to encompass the estimated autocorrelation values.  However, I want to extend this axis range over all allowable correlation values (i.e., from negative one to positive one).  Unfortunately, when I do this, the axis labels do not adjust to the new range, and the labels get squashed.

Below is my code and output:

```
* Generate the residual autocorrelation plot
* (taken with respect to id variable)

tsset id

ac stud_res, lags(12) yscale(r(-1,1)) ///
title("Residual Autocorrelation Plot") ///
ytitle("Estimated Autocorrelation") ///
```

[image]

How can I get a plot with the desired extension to the vertical axis, but without having the labels squashed only onto the range of the plot values?

Answer (score 4):

You have two choices and both involve adjusting the `ylabel()` option while removing `yscale()`:

```
ac stud_res, lags(12) ylabel(-1(0.4)1) title("Residual Autocorrelation Plot") ///
ytitle("Estimated Autocorrelation")
```

[image]

and

```
ac stud_res, lags(12) ylabel(#5) title("Residual Autocorrelation Plot") ///
ytitle("Estimated Autocorrelation")
```

[image]